# Is there a version of Youtube Chromeless player that works on iPad/iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, youtube, embed, chromeless

I'm building a site which requires being able to have advanced control over a video embed. I'd like to use the Chromeless player.

The [example from Google](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/chromeless_example_1.html) is flash based. Is there an alternative version that can be used without flash?

Comment: The example from Google now works on iPad when I open it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing to the Chromeless Youtube palyer that would work for the iPhone/iPad, seems to be using [HTML5 iframe with Youtube API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/iframe_api_reference.html).